# as3 rtmp connection error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to add a rtmp vedio url in my stage. but its showing error:

> Error #2126: NetConnection object must be connected.  at
>   flash.net::NetStream/ctor()   at flash.net::NetStream()   at
>   main()[/Users/user/Desktop/ojotha/main.as:15] Cannot display source
>   code at this location.

here is my code

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.media.Video;

    public class main extends MovieClip {
        var streamserver:String="rtmp://216.245.200.114/live";
        var streamname:String="shomoy";

        public function main() {
            var netconnection:NetConnection=new NetConnection();
            netconnection.connect(streamserver);
            var netstream:NetStream=new NetStream(netconnection);
            var video:Video=new Video();
            video.attachNetStream(netstream);
            netstream.play(streamname);
            video.height=480;
            video.width=640;
            addChild(video);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what this is saying is that you have to wait for the NetConnection to have finished its connection and sent the netStatus event NetConnection.Connect.Success.  Until this is received, the connection hasn't been established, and you can't create the NetStream.